# Python: Print list of unknown length?

Tags: python, html, image, printing

I'm trying to use python to print an html file.

Is there a way to incorporate the following into the print statement? Perhaps using the format method?

Current situation:

```
foo = ['some_image1.com', 'some_image2.com']

print '''<img src="' + foo[0] + '">
<img src="' + foo[1] + '">
<img src="' + foo[2] + '">''' # Desired behavior to ignore foo[2]
```

How can I get past this? Should I not use a list?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print ''.join(map('<img src="{}">'.format, foo))
```

or

```
print '<img src="%s">' * len(foo) % tuple(foo)
```

(if `foo` already were a tuple, you wouldn't need the `tuple(...)`).

I wouldn't do the latter, though, except when code golfing (where I recently did use this).

Answer (score 2):

```
print "\n".join('<img src="%s">' % src for src in foo)
```

Comment: He said something about wanting to ignore "foo[2]", but I'm very unclear on what that means.

Comment: @Will: I was confused for a bit too, but then guessed he wanted to stop with `foo[1]` because the example list only has two elements. However, without a loop or recursion or comprehension you are stuck with hardcoding for a particular length.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: `*` has a loop inside its definition, as does `join`.

Comment: Yeah ok, if you look at it that way. I don't think many people would, though :-). Otherwise you might as well go a step or two further, to CPU instruction processing, and say that *everything* is done as a loop.